# Why I don't get any results from this simple java web-crawler application?

Tags: java, web-crawler

The basic source code is from [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ThirdParty/WebCrawler/)

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WebCrawler extends Applet implements ActionListener, Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String SEARCH = "Search";
    public static final String STOP = "Stop";
    public static final String DISALLOW = "Disallow:";
    public static final int SEARCH_LIMIT = 50;
    Panel panelMain;
    List listMatches;
    Label labelStatus;
    // URLs to be searched
    Vector<String> vectorToSearch;
    // URLs already searched
    Vector<String> vectorSearched;
    // URLs which match
    Vector<String> vectorMatches;
    Thread searchThread;
    TextField textURL;
    Choice choiceType;

public void init()
{
    // set up the main UI panel
    panelMain = new Panel();
    panelMain.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    // text entry components
    Panel panelEntry = new Panel();
    panelEntry.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    Panel panelURL = new Panel();
    panelURL.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
    Label labelURL = new Label("Starting URL: ", Label.RIGHT);
    panelURL.add(labelURL);
    textURL = new TextField("", 40);
    panelURL.add(textURL);
    panelEntry.add("North", panelURL);
    Panel panelType = new Panel();
    panelType.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT, 5, 5));
    Label labelType = new Label("Content type: ", Label.RIGHT);
    panelType.add(labelType);
    choiceType = new Choice();
    choiceType.addItem("text/html");
    choiceType.addItem("audio/basic");
    choiceType.addItem("audio/au");
    choiceType.addItem("audio/aiff");
    choiceType.addItem("audio/wav");
    choiceType.addItem("video/mpeg");
    choiceType.addItem("video/x-avi");
    panelType.add(choiceType);
    panelEntry.add("South", panelType);
    panelMain.add("North", panelEntry);
    // list of result URLs
    Panel panelListButtons = new Panel();
    panelListButtons.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    Panel panelList = new Panel();
    panelList.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    Label labelResults = new Label("Search results");
    panelList.add("North", labelResults);
    Panel panelListCurrent = new Panel();
    panelListCurrent.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    listMatches = new List(10);
    panelListCurrent.add("North", listMatches);
    labelStatus = new Label("");
    panelListCurrent.add("South", labelStatus);
    panelList.add("South", panelListCurrent);
    panelListButtons.add("North", panelList);
    // control buttons
    Panel panelButtons = new Panel();
    Button buttonSearch = new Button(SEARCH);
    buttonSearch.addActionListener(this);
    panelButtons.add(buttonSearch);
    Button buttonStop = new Button(STOP);
    buttonStop.addActionListener(this);
    panelButtons.add(buttonStop);
    panelListButtons.add("South", panelButtons);
    panelMain.add("South", panelListButtons);
    add(panelMain);
    setVisible(true);
    repaint();
    // initialize search data structures
    vectorToSearch = new Vector<String>();
    vectorSearched = new Vector<String>();
    vectorMatches = new Vector<String>();
    // set default for URL access
    URLConnection.setDefaultAllowUserInteraction(false);
}

public void start()
{}

public void stop()
{
    if (searchThread != null)
    {
        setStatus("stopping...");
        searchThread = null;
    }
}

public void destroy()
{}

boolean robotSafe(URL url)
{
    String strHost = url.getHost();
    // form URL of the robots.txt file
    String strRobot = "http://" + strHost + "/robots.txt";
    URL urlRobot;
    try
    {
        urlRobot = new URL(strRobot);
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {
        // something weird is happening, so don't trust it
        return false;
    }
    String strCommands;
    try
    {
        InputStream urlRobotStream = urlRobot.openStream();
        // read in entire file
        byte b[] = new byte[1000];
        int numRead = urlRobotStream.read(b);
        strCommands = new String(b, 0, numRead);
        while (numRead != -1)
        {
            if (Thread.currentThread() != searchThread) break;
            numRead = urlRobotStream.read(b);
            if (numRead != -1)
            {
                String newCommands = new String(b, 0, numRead);
                strCommands += newCommands;
            }
        }
        urlRobotStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // if there is no robots.txt file, it is OK to search
        return true;
    }
    // assume that this robots.txt refers to us and
    // search for "Disallow:" commands.
    String strURL = url.getFile();
    int index = 0;
    while ((index = strCommands.indexOf(DISALLOW, index)) != -1)
    {
        index += DISALLOW.length();
        String strPath = strCommands.substring(index);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(strPath);
        if (!st.hasMoreTokens()) break;
        String strBadPath = st.nextToken();
        // if the URL starts with a disallowed path, it is not safe
        if (strURL.indexOf(strBadPath) == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    // Draw a Rectangle around the applet's display area.
    g.drawRect(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
    panelMain.paint(g);
    panelMain.paintComponents(g);
    // update(g);
    // panelMain.update(g);
}

public void run()
{
    String strURL = textURL.getText();
    String strTargetType = choiceType.getSelectedItem();
    int numberSearched = 0;
    int numberFound = 0;
    if (strURL.length() == 0)
    {
        setStatus("ERROR: must enter a starting URL");
        return;
    }
    // initialize search data structures
    vectorToSearch.removeAllElements();
    vectorSearched.removeAllElements();
    vectorMatches.removeAllElements();
    listMatches.removeAll();
    vectorToSearch.addElement(strURL);
    while ((vectorToSearch.size() > 0) && (Thread.currentThread() == searchThread))
    {
        // get the first element from the to be searched list
        strURL = (String) vectorToSearch.elementAt(0);
        setStatus("searching " + strURL);
        URL url;
        try
        {
            url = new URL(strURL);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            setStatus("ERROR: invalid URL " + strURL);
            break;
        }
        // mark the URL as searched (we want this one way or the other)
        vectorToSearch.removeElementAt(0);
        vectorSearched.addElement(strURL);
        // can only search http: protocol URLs
        if (url.getProtocol().compareTo("http") != 0) break;
        // test to make sure it is before searching
        if (!robotSafe(url)) break;
        try
        {
            // try opening the URL
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            InputStream urlStream = url.openStream();
            String type = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(urlStream);
            if (type == null) break;
            if (type.compareTo("text/html") != 0) break;
            // search the input stream for links
            // first, read in the entire URL
            byte b[] = new byte[1000];
            int numRead = urlStream.read(b);
            String content = new String(b, 0, numRead);
            while (numRead != -1)
            {
                if (Thread.currentThread() != searchThread) break;
                numRead = urlStream.read(b);
                if (numRead != -1)
                {
                    String newContent = new String(b, 0, numRead);
                    content += newContent;
                }
            }
            urlStream.close();
            if (Thread.currentThread() != searchThread) break;
            String lowerCaseContent = content.toLowerCase();
            int index = 0;
            while ((index = lowerCaseContent.indexOf("<a", index)) != -1)
            {
                if ((index = lowerCaseContent.indexOf("href", index)) == -1) break;
                if ((index = lowerCaseContent.indexOf("=", index)) == -1) break;
                if (Thread.currentThread() != searchThread) break;
                index++;
                String remaining = content.substring(index);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(remaining, "\t\n\r\">#");
                String strLink = st.nextToken();
                URL urlLink;
                try
                {
                    urlLink = new URL(url, strLink);
                    strLink = urlLink.toString();
                }
                catch (MalformedURLException e)
                {
                    setStatus("ERROR: bad URL " + strLink);
                    continue;
                }
                // only look at http links
                if (urlLink.getProtocol().compareTo("http") != 0) break;
                if (Thread.currentThread() != searchThread) break;
                try
                {
                    // try opening the URL
                    URLConnection urlLinkConnection = urlLink.openConnection();
                    urlLinkConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    InputStream linkStream = urlLink.openStream();
                    String strType =
                            URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(linkStream);
                    linkStream.close();
                    // if another page, add to the end of search list
                    if (strType == null) break;
                    if (strType.compareTo("text/html") == 0)
                    {
                        // check to see if this URL has already been
                        // searched or is going to be searched
                        if ((!vectorSearched.contains(strLink)) &&
                                (!vectorToSearch.contains(strLink)))
                        {
                            // test to make sure it is robot-safe!
                            if (robotSafe(urlLink)) vectorToSearch
                                    .addElement(strLink);
                        }
                    }
                    // if the proper type, add it to the results list
                    // unless we have already seen it
                    if (strType.compareTo(strTargetType) == 0)
                    {
                        if (vectorMatches.contains(strLink) == false)
                        {
                            listMatches.add(strLink);
                            vectorMatches.addElement(strLink);
                            numberFound++;
                            if (numberFound >= SEARCH_LIMIT) break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    setStatus("ERROR: couldn't open URL " + strLink);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            setStatus("ERROR: couldn't open URL " + strURL);
            break;
        }
        numberSearched++;
        if (numberSearched >= SEARCH_LIMIT) break;
    }
    if (numberSearched >= SEARCH_LIMIT || numberFound >= SEARCH_LIMIT) setStatus("reached search limit of " +
            SEARCH_LIMIT);
    else setStatus("done");
    searchThread = null;
    // searchThread.stop();
}

void setStatus(String status)
{
    labelStatus.setText(status);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    String command = event.getActionCommand();
    if (command.compareTo(SEARCH) == 0)
    {
        setStatus("searching...");
        // launch a thread to do the search
        if (searchThread == null)
        {
            searchThread = new Thread(this);
        }
        searchThread.start();
    }
    else if (command.compareTo(STOP) == 0)
    {
        stop();
    }
}

public static void main(String argv[])
{
    Frame f = new Frame("WebFrame");
    WebCrawler applet = new WebCrawler();
    f.add("Center", applet);
    /*
     * Behind a firewall set your proxy and port here!
     */
    // Properties props= new Properties(System.getProperties());
    // props.put("http.proxySet", "true");
    // props.put("http.proxyHost", "webcache-cup");
    // props.put("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    //
    // Properties newprops = new Properties(props);
    // System.setProperties(newprops);
    /**/
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    f.pack();
    // f.show();
    }
 }
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: http.proxySet is an urban myth. It has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because of this line:

```
String type = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(urlStream);
```

Which returned `null` for most of the sites I tried it against.  This method is a serious hack.  Even James Gosling, father of the Java language and the man who originally wrote this method, admits this in [early API docs](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/apidocs/java.net.URLConnection.html):

```
guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream)
// This disgusting hack is used to check for files have some type that can be determined by inspection.
```

This wording has been removed in the latest API docs, but the method is still a hack.  Here's a snippet of the code:

```
static public String guessContentTypeFromStream(InputStream is)
{
is.mark(12);
int c1 = is.read();
int c2 = is.read();
int c3 = is.read();
int c4 = is.read();
int c5 = is.read();
int c6 = is.read();
int c7 = is.read();
int c8 = is.read();
int c9 = is.read();
int c10 = is.read();
int c11 = is.read();
is.reset();

if (c1 == '<') {
    if (c2 == '!'
    || ((c2 == 'h' && (c3 == 't' && c4 == 'm' && c5 == 'l' ||
               c3 == 'e' && c4 == 'a' && c5 == 'd') ||
    (c2 == 'b' && c3 == 'o' && c4 == 'd' && c5 == 'y'))) ||
    ((c2 == 'H' && (c3 == 'T' && c4 == 'M' && c5 == 'L' ||
            c3 == 'E' && c4 == 'A' && c5 == 'D') ||
    (c2 == 'B' && c3 == 'O' && c4 == 'D' && c5 == 'Y')))) {
    return "text/html";
    }
}
```

What is it doing?  Reading the first eleven bytes and seeing if it says `<!`, `<html`, `<head`, `<body`, `<HTML`, `<HEAD` or `<BODY`.

Seriously.  This is the shipping code in Java 6.  This might even qualify for a [DailyWTF](http://thedailywtf.com/) [CodeSOD](http://thedailywtf.com/Series/CodeSOD.aspx). *

So anyway, webpages don't do this anymore, even if they did in 1998 when that article was written.  Talking of which, the code in the article is pretty awful too, by today's standards. I wouldn't even try to salvage it.  I would look at [some of the much better open-source web-crawlers](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-web-crawlers-java) out there.

- All due respect to Gosling.  This was the 'right' way to do it in the day - even doing individual character comparisons rather than String comparisons, presumably for efficiency - but the fact that it's still shipping and hasn't been deprecated or improved is pretty abysmal, IMHO.